# Detecting stopped/interupted video stream with JWPlayer7

Tags: jwplayer7

I've been trying all the error detection with the JWPlayer API, and can't seem to be able to detect if the video stream has been stopped, or interrupted.  While watching the video, i turn off my network connection, which (I presume) should trigger an error, but instead, it just hangs until i close the page.

*Is* there an error that should fire in such a case, or is there some other way to detect when this problem occurs?